# How to select the first line from each file in a directory and print it into a new text file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a directory with several `.txt` files.

From each of these files, I want to select the first line and print it into a new `.txt` file (to get a list of all the first lines).

I tried it with the `awk` and `sed` commands and combined it with a loop, but without success.

Answer (score 31):

Use `head`:

```
head -n1 -q *.txt > new-file
```

- `-n1` tells `head` to extract the first line only.
- `-q` tells head not to print the filename.

On OS X (and probably on some other *nix variants) the `-q` option is not supported by `head`. You need to remove the filenames yourself, e.g.

```
head -n1 *.txt | grep -v '==> ' > new-file
```

This only works if you know the output shouldn't contain the `==>`  string. To be absolutely sure, use a loop (which will be much slower than running `head` just once):

```
for file in *.txt ; do
    head -n1 "$file"
done
```

Comment: This doesn't work on OS X: `head: illegal option -- q`

Comment: @Travis: Check the update.

Comment: Also, I'm kind of confused why you're searching for OS X related advice in a Ubuntu forum.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. I wasn't searching this forum per se, this was just one of the first results on Google. I guess you're right that and technically, answers here should only have to be applicable to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 9):

Using `grep`:

```
grep -m 1 '.' *.txt >output.file
```

`grep` will match any character and will exit after first match i.e. `grep` will output the first lines of all the input files  and we are saving those in `out.txt`.

Comment: I like this, it's a nice little hack.

Answer (score 2):

Using only Bash:

```bsh
for f in *.txt; do <"$f" read line; printf "$line\n" >>new.txt; done
```

- `*.txt` is expanded to the list of folders / files ending with `.txt` in the current working directory (since there are only files folders ending with `.txt` are not a concern);
- `<"$f" read line` reads one line from the file path stored in `f` and stores it in `line`;
- `printf "$line\n" >>new.txt`: appends the content of `line` to `new.txt`;

```
% cat foo.txt 
line #1 in foo
line #2 in foo
line #3 in foo

% cat bar.txt
line #1 in bar
line #2 in bar
line #3 in bar

% for f in *.txt; do <"$f" read line; printf "$line\n" >>new.txt; done

% cat new.txt 
line #1 in bar
line #1 in foo
```

Comment: kos, a bit lengthy but here is +1..

Comment: @heemayl But it's Bash-only. ;)

Comment: BTW congrats on 15k :)

Comment: @heemayl Thanks :D. Honestly I'm checking out the site like crazy just for the sake of protecting a question XD

Answer (score 0):

You have tried it with `awk`, here is a `awk` version

```
awk 'FNR==1 {print} {nextfile}' *.txt > out
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with AWK is to tell AWK to print, but then immediately go to next file

```
tmp:$ touch file1 file2 file3

tmp:$ printf  "Line 1 \n Line 2" | tee file1 file2 file3
Line 1 
 Line 2
tmp:$ awk '{print;nextfile}' file1 file2 file3
Line 1 
Line 1 
Line 1
```

`sed` also allows printing of specific lines . Here I've combined that with `find`

```
tmp:$ find . -name "file*" -exec  sed -n '1p' {} \;                            
Line 1 
Line 1 
Line 1
```

And perl:

```
tmp:$ find . -name "file*"  -exec perl -ne 'print  if 1..1' {} \;              
Line 1 
Line 1 
Line 1
```

And last but not least , `grep`

```
tmp:$ grep -n 1 file1 file2 file3                                              
file1:1:Line 1 
file2:1:Line 1 
file3:1:Line 1
```

Saving everything to a single file is just a matter of appending `> outputFile.txt` at the end of these commands.